# The code writing string on a string but next to it

Tags: c, arrays, string

The code working well. But when user enter a string it writes on same location.I want it writing next to him. like the 5 lenght word "EARTH" and 2.
input is "MARS"

I want like this  ///// but it happens like this now

- array[0]= 'E'//// - array[0]=M
- array[ 1]= 'A'          ////- array[0]= A
- array[2]= 'R'           ////- array[0]= R
- array[3]= 'T'           ////- array[0]= S
- array[4]= 'H'           ////- array[0]= H
- array[5]= ' '
- array[6]= 'M'
- array[7]= 'A'
- array[8]= 'R'
- array[9]= 'S'

  - I tried to use that [^\n] think but it did not work (i think i cant do it right)
  - I tried scanf(
  - I tried getline()

```c
         #include <stdio.h>
         #include <string.h>
         #include <time.h>
         #include <stdlib.h>

         char str[10][20];

         void getting_veriables(),printing();



        int main (){

         getting_veriables();
         printing();
         }

        void printing() {

        int x,y;    
        for(x = 0;x<10;x++){
        printf("\n");
        for(y = 0;y<20;y++){
        printf(" |%c| ",str[x][y]);
              }
            }
          }

          void getting_veriables(){
          int length=0,limit,a=0;

           printf("How many word's you will enter ? : ");
        scanf("%d",&limit); 
            // taking how much word will be enter

            if(limit<=10 && limit>=3){ 
            a=1;
            }
            else{
        printf("You can enter min 3 max 10 words\n");
        a=0; // I will replace it with exit think.
        system("PAUSE");
        }

            for(;limit!=0 && a==1;limit--){

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Please enter your words : ");
            gets(str); // the problem is here i think.
            length = strlen(str); // taking lenght of the word.


            if(length > 20 || length < 3)
            {
            printf("Your number must be between 3-20 lenght\n");
            exit(1);
             }
           }
         }
```

It writes Input 1 = Example Input 2 = Think on up left corner.

[image: Like this]

Comment: `str` is a 2D array.  If you pass that into `gets`, it's always going to write in the first position.  Keep a counter (e.g. `stridx`) and use `gets(str[stridx])`.  Actually, don't use `gets` at all!  It's unsafe.  Use `fgets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Avoid using `gets`, it is deprecated and dangerous.
2. You are writing all your input to the same memory location, `str`, which will overwrite your old data as you are experiencing. You want to write your second input after to the first, so you need to add the length of the first input to `str`:

Example:

```
gets(str + length);
// "EARTH\0\0\0\0"
//  ^ str               // 1st input gets stored starting here
//       ^ str + length // 2nd starting here
```

You then also want to increase the length, instead of overriding it:

```
length += strlen(str)
```

If you want to add a space, you simply increment the `length`:

```
str[length] = ' ';
length += 1;
```

Comment: "to add a space" --> `str[length] = ' '; length += 1;` is not sufficient to insure `str` remains a _string_. Alternative: `str[length++] = ' '; str[length] = '\0';`

Comment: `length += strlen(str)` will not work as desired.  Did you want `length += strlen(str + length)`?

Comment: Yeah it works like that but the output does not what i wanted.I'm working on it. @YoYoYonnY

Comment: Think the array[x][y] when i write code like yours it add's the first word on x=1 y=Lenght of the word and after it it addes the lenght on x axis and write next word in x+lenght of the word but i want it end of the y axis i know it's complicated but if you dont understand i can draw a pitcure of it.

Answer (score 0):

From your declaration,

```
   char str[10][20];
```

It appears that your intention is to store at-most 10 strings, each not exceeding 20 characters in length.

And your guess as to where the problem might be, looks to be correct.

```
    gets(str); // the problem is here i think.
```

gets(str) is the same as gets(&str[0]), and so you end up reading into the same index over and over.
You should be able to fix this by rewriting the for loop as below -

```
for(i=0; i<limit && a==1; i++){
    .  .   .
    gets(str[i]); // the problem is here i think.
    length = strlen(str[i]); // taking lenght of the word.
   .   .   .
}
```